# Book about kids using mental powers to try to push the Earth off its axis in order to destroy it

Tags: story-identification, novel, telekinesis

I read a book before 1970 about children with telekinetic powers, who try to push the Earth off its axis in order to destroy it. One kid imagined a lever and the other imagined a fulcrum they would use to push the Earth with their mental powers. Their teacher discovered what they were doing and stopped them.

Comment: Is this a novel or a short story? It doesn't sound enough plot for a novel unless the lever-fulcrum-Earth business is just a small part of the novel.